# No exact matches in call to instance method 'append' when adding string to array of strings

Tags: swiftui

I am trying to append string ids from one struct (drinks) instance into an array of strings in another (venues). Both structs are stored in firestore and the id in question is a DocumentID.

Even when I use conditional binding to unwrap the string, I get the no exact matches error. My two struct are defined as follows:

1:

```
struct Venue: Codable, Identifiable {
    @DocumentID var id: String?
    var name: String
    var address: String?
    var drinks: [String]?
}
```

2:

```
struct Drink: Codable, Identifiable {
    @DocumentID var id: String?
    var name: String
    var brand: String
    }
```

When I've built an array of [Drink], I have the following code to write the ids to the array in the Venue:

```
Button {
    for drink in drinksServedByVenue {
        if let drinkID = drink.id {
            confirmedVenue.drinks.append(drinkID)
        }
    }
}
```

And this where I get the error "No exact matches in call to instance method 'append'"

I'm confused because both values contain strings and are optional at instance creation.

Any tips greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than *conditional binding* you need ***optional chaining***.
`drinks` is an optional and you cannot append something to `nil`

```
Button {
    for drink in drinksServedByVenue {
        if let drinkID = drink.id {
            confirmedVenue.drinks?.append(drinkID)
        }
    }
}
```

If `drinks` has a value the `id` is appended, if not the code after the question mark is skipped and the code continues in the next line.

You can write the entire expression in a *swiftier* way

```
Button {
    confirmedVenue.drinks?.append(contentsOf: drinksServedByVenue.compactMap(\.id))
}
```

Comment: Thanks vadian! That worked - after resolving issues with the declaration of the var, and with the preview. Such a simple change that I feel like I must have tried it before, but maybe not. Or maybe I didn't address the other bugs.